# Swift 3: Array.contains(customObject)

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to implement the if block seen below:

```
    if loggedInUser.following.contains(userToView) {

    }
```

where `loggedInUser.following` is an array of a custom `User` class and userToView is a single instance of the `User` class.

```
class User {
    ....
}
```

However, `loggedInUser.following.contains(userToView)` is throwing the error seen below:

**Cannot convert value of type 'User' to expected argument type '(User) throws -> Bool'**

I am under the impression I will need to implement some sort of a function that determines if two users are equal, but i have no idea how to implement such a function. Any help would be much appreciated; thank you in advance!

Comment: to use contains you will need to make your User class conform to Equatable protocol

Comment: `class User: Equatable {
    let name: String
    required init(name: String) {
       self.name = name
    }
}
func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool { return lhs.name == rhs.name }
`

Comment: `let users = [User(name: "a"),User(name: "b")]` and 
`users.contains(User(name: "z"))  // false`

Comment: Thank you, after googling the Equitable Protocol, I was able to follow the yellow brick road; which lead me to implementing the function you just suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for the suggestions.

**Everything worked as expected after creating the following function and implementing the "Equatable" Protocol:**

```
class User: Equatable {
    //...
    var id = Int() //Unique Identifier
    //...
}

func ==(lhs: User, rhs: User) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}
```

**and after implementing the above code i was able to call the following without any problems:**

```
if loggedInUser.following.contains(userToView) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use the code below

```
if (loggedInUser.following as NSArray).contains(userToView) {

}
```